# How to get position of div inside td

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating calendar in php, html, css and jquery.

My table is like this :

```
<table>
   <tr bgcolor="silver" id="10"> 
      <td style="width:10%;" id="resource10">Mausami Pandit</td>
      <td style="width:70px;" class="tbDay" id="resource10">
             <div class="08:01" style="display:inline; position:relative;"></div>
               .
               .
               .
             <div class="08:30" style="display:inline; position:relative;"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width:70px;" class="tbDay" id="resource10">                                                  <div class="08:31" style="display:inline; position:relative;"></div>                                                                .
               .
               .
              <div class="08:30" style="display:inline; position:relative;"></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is for one hour and i have it like this for each hour from 08:00 to 18:30.

Now i want to select the div of a particular time and need to change the background color.
Means i want to change the color of a particular time slot.

I tried to select div like this :

```
  $('td#resource10').find('div.08:31').addClass('test');
```

but its not working.

Can anyone tell me where is my mistake ?

or how can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: then can i add id like 08:30 ?

Comment: Isn't it invalid to have css class name starting with numerical characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p7BEf/1/)**

First you have multiple element with ID `resource10`.
This is wrong.

Second you have `:` in your classname, so catch them with `~` selector:

```
$('.tbDay').find('[class~="08:30"]').addClass('test');
```

---

Thanks to [**BrunoLM**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340760/brunolm), you can also use this:

```
$('.tbDay').find('.08\\:30').addClass('test');
```

---

Although jQuery will handle the multiple same IDs for you in this case:

```
$('#resource10').find('[class~="08:30"]').addClass('test');
```

I suggest you don't use multiple elements with same ID.

Comment: I cant change the td id like this. because i have each tr for each resource.

Comment: @Mausami so get the `td` by classname, look at updated answer.

Comment: hey i change your previous answer with this and its working.
$('#resource10').find('[class~="08:30"]').addClass('test');

Comment: yes.. BrunoLM is also right. And your ans with tilled '~' sign is also right. so Please change your answer so that i can accept it as my answer.